# ListView.builder doesn't show anything - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

When I'm, not using the ListView.builder constructor in Flutter, the individual item is shown as expected from the JSON API:

when I use ListView.builder, nothing shows up. no Error!

I also tried a listview with Texts only that doesn't seem to work either. 
Here's the code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Container(

 child: new Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("the title"),//TODO edit this
         backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),

     body:
     Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
           future: getPosts2(),
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

             return snapshot.hasData
                 ? ListViewPosts(postsFrom: snapshot.data)
                 : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
           },
         ),


       ],
     ),

 ),
  );
 }
 }
```

And here is the ListViewPosts Stateless Widget:

```
     class ListViewPosts extends 
     StatelessWidget {
     final List<dynamic> postsFrom;

     ListViewPosts({Key key, 
     this.postsFrom}) : super(key: key);

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
      placeholder: 'assets/images/placeholder.png',
      image: postsFrom[1]["featured_media"] == 0
          ? 'assets/images/placeholder.png'
          : postsFrom[1]["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"]
      [0]["source_url"],


    ),

    FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
      placeholder: 'assets/images/placeholder.png',
      image: postsFrom[2]["featured_media"] == 0
          ? 'assets/images/placeholder.png'
          : postsFrom[2]["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"]
      [0]["source_url"],


    ),
    new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            "نووسه‌ر: " +
                postsFrom[1]["_embedded"]["author"][0]
                ["name"],
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            dateConvertor(
                postsFrom[2]["date"].toString()),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),

    ListView.builder(
      itemCount: postsFrom.length, //== null ? 0 : postsFrom.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(postsFrom.toString()),
              Container(
                child: hawalImage(postsFrom, index),
              ),
              new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: new ListTile(

                  title: new Text("whatEver"),
                  subtitle: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: new Text(postsFrom[index]["title"]["rendered"]),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: hawalDate(postsFrom, index),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new ButtonTheme.bar(
                child: hawalBtnBar(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Comment: you dont return anything from your `itemBuilder`

Comment: I'm returning snapshot data to my postsFrom variable .

Comment: no, you are not, but it seems you already know what to do...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to write `return Card` at the beginning of the curly brackets in the builder function. Also I would be cautious with using `Expanded` there, it might cause some errors.

Also you put a `ListView` inside a `Column` without defining it's height, so it will take up space indefinitely. Wrap it in a widget that provides height constraints(`SizedBox`, `Expanded`, ...)

Comment: thanks, buddy, me being a noob and not returning the card :-*

Comment: Aaaah, fell in that same trap too. Thanks man!

Answer (score 6):

Inside the `Listview.builder()` you could try to add the property `shrinkWrap: true`.

This worked for me. I was facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use with `Expanded`. Hopefully, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `return Card` at the beginning of the curly brackets in the builder function. Also I would be cautious with using `Expanded` there, it might cause some errors.

Comment: I have tried with return Card , also without Expanded. 
I have tried one with only text elements but still, nothing shows up.